# Location of the manual mocks folder __mocks__ when using Jest

Tags: jestjs

So the Jest docs specify that the `__mocks__` folder be at the same level as the node_modules folder when manual mocking a node module (axios in this case), and gets picked up automatically. We needed to reference the mocked module, and so put it in the src folder which is one level down from the node_modules.

node_modules

src/`__mocks__`/

We found that even though it was not in the required location as "specified" in the jest docs, jest still correctly picks up the module from `__mocks__`, instead of from node_modules.

As this is not following the documented behaviour, can we rely on this behaviour? Or as its not documented, could it be subject to change? If it is meant to work, then should the docs be amended?

Comment: You can put mocks in subdirectories https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules

Comment: @AndyRay thats for user modules. Here we are mocking a node module. For that the docs specify a different location.

Comment: You need to set [roots](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#roots-arraystring) 
 > the mock should be placed in the `__mocks__` directory adjacent to node_modules (unless you configured __roots__ to point to a folder other than the project root)